# Cannot read property '0' of undefined with custom filter pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

Since I have created and added a custom filter pipe for an array I get this exception when the view loads:

```
TesttypesListComponent - inline template:35:14 caused by: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

This must have something todo I guess with how I load the data.

Before I added the pipe data loading worked!

I can put a breakpoint into the pipe but it never gets hit inside due to the error.

Anyone has an idea what I do wrong with my first pipe?

**PIPE**

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'TestTypePipe'
})
export class TestTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(testTypes, args?) {
        let [currentSubject, currentSchoolclass] = args;
        if (!currentSubject || !currentSchoolclass) {
            return [];
        }
        else {
            return testTypes.filter(s => {
                return s.subjectId == currentSubject.subjectId && s.schoolclassId == currentSchoolclass.schoolclassId;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let t of testTypes | TestTypePipe:currentSubject:currentSchoolclass; let i = index">
            <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="getTemplate(t)" [ngOutletContext]="{ $implicit: t, index: i }"></template>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
  currentSubject: Subject;
  currentSchoolclass: Schoolclass;

      ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.schoolyearId = parseInt(params['id']); });

        this.testService.getTestTypes(this.schoolyearId).subscribe(data => {
          this.schoolclasses = data.schoolclasses.map(m => new Schoolclass(m));
          this.subjects = data.subjects.map(m => new Subject(m));

          for (let t of data.testTypes) {
            t.viewMode = ViewMode.Displaying;
            let testType = new AssignedTestType(t);
            this.testTypes.push(testType)
          }
        }
```

);
      }

Comment: Will the pipe be invoked if you remove the parameters `:currentSubject:currentSchoolclass` ?

Comment: Then I get this error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at TestTypePipe.transform (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:72680:34) at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:20150:22 at => Seems I will outcomment and console.log some stuff tomorrow to find the undefined...

Comment: hum, right, that's because of the let line inside transform, it tries to read parameters from an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pipe#transform` takes optional top-level arguments, not a single `args: []`.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'TestTypePipe'
})
export class TestTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(testTypes, ...args) {
        let [currentSubject, currentSchoolclass] = args;
        if (!currentSubject || !currentSchoolclass) {
            return [];
        }
        else {
            return testTypes.filter(s => {
                return s.subjectId == currentSubject.subjectId && s.schoolclassId == currentSchoolclass.schoolclassId;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works now, seems I read an outdated blog due to the ...args and args? problem!